# running rosmsg show from code

Tags: rospy, roscpp, rostopic, rosmsg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

is there a way (possibly in Python) to call the command line command `rosmsg show` from code, passing as an argument the name of the message/service and getting an object representing the message/the class with the message structure? I know that some commands can be called from `rospy` (as `rostopic list`, for example), but I can't find how to run `rosmsg`.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/249406/running-rosmsg-show-from-code/) by [McKracken82](https://answers.ros.org/users/26321/mckracken82/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2016-12-05

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2016-12-05**:
What do you really want to achieve? This sounds like an [xy-problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)

**Comment by [McKracken82](https://answers.ros.org/users/26321/mckracken82/) on 2016-12-05**:
I need to build instances of all the ros messages and services in a KB, so I need to understand which are all the messages/services being published, and which re their structures in terms of submessages/primitive types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The command line tool calls a single function (https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/6a0672c0189024e38bfe51d917dea148f76fccf7/tools/rosmsg/scripts/rosmsg#L34-L35) which you can call directly in Python.

You could also call any API which is using behind this directly, e.g. `rosmsg_cmd_show` (https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/6a0672c0189024e38bfe51d917dea148f76fccf7/tools/rosmsg/src/rosmsg/__init__.py#L745).

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2016-12-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [McKracken82](https://answers.ros.org/users/26321/mckracken82/) on 2016-12-06**:
Great, that was exactly what I was searching for, although I thought messages were managed in a more object-oriented like structure. Anyway, that worked perfectly. Thanks!